# How to show Grid Lines in Open Office Draw permanently

Tags: api, openoffice.org, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, uno

I am programmatically drawing a flowchart using Java UNO Runtime Reference in which I want to display grid Lines permanently.Using following code I was able to display the Grid Lines but they are toggled ON and OFF alternately when the code executes.

```
XModel xModel = (XModel) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XModel.class, xDrawDoc);
    XController xController = xModel.getCurrentController();
    XDispatchProvider xDisp = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDispatchProvider.class, xController);
    XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = xContext.getServiceManager();
    Object dispatchHelper = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper", xContext);
    XDispatchHelper xDispatchHelper = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDispatchHelper.class, dispatchHelper);
    PropertyValue[] navigatorDesc = new PropertyValue[1];
    navigatorDesc[0] = new PropertyValue();
    navigatorDesc[0].Name = "GridVisible";
    navigatorDesc[0].Value = true;
    xDispatchHelper.executeDispatch(xDisp, ".uno:GridVisible" , "", 0, navigatorDesc);
```

I want to permanently show Grid Lines.How can I achieve this using Java.Pls suggest. If there is any way of checking whether the Grid Lines are ON(any method which could return a boolean value), this could also be a useful approach.